# How to give runtime paging to tables in mvc3.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating the runtime table in mvc3.net. From controller i am getting the json collection and in view am creating the runtime table according to json collection

first am just initialising the table

```
<div id="DisplayBookChapterList" class="fLeft per30 mr15">        
    <table class="contentTable" id="tblDisplayChapterList" >            
         </table>
```

In Runtime am populating the table rows by below given code

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetBookChapterList", "CourseManagement")" + '/' + bookname,  function (data) {
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
                BookChapterlist += '<tr><td style="display:none" id=ChapterListBookID value=' + val.BookID + '>' + val.BookID + '</td><td>' + val.ChapterNo + ' </td><td>' + val.Title + '</td><td><input type=checkbox id="' + val.ChapterID + '"></td></tr>';

}
});               
$('#DisplayBookChapterList table').append(BookChapterlist);
```

I want to give paging to this dynamically created table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to create the paging links to select a specific page, next, previous, first, last or whatever you need. E.g.

```
<ul>        
    @foreach (var page in Enumerable.Range(1, numPages)) {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink(page.ToString(), "GetBookChapterList", "CourseManagement", new {page}, new {@class = "page-link"})</li>
    }        
</ul>
```

Note that all links have the css class "page-link".

On the server side, add a "page" parameter to your action so you know which page to fetch in the controller.

Now, back to the HTML code: the href of each link is the address where to fetch the data from and we can use this in our JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(".page-link").on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.getJSON($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The nice thing about this approach is that you can make it easily fall back for clients that have JavaScript disabled: in the "GetBookChapterList" action, check if the request is an ajax request (Request.IsAjaxRequest()). If so, return the required JSON data. If not, render a normal, full page showing the selected page of the table.

This is generally a good approach: if possible, make sure the site works without JavaScript, then add JavaScript to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Add an optional 'Page' parameter to your GetBookChapterList action method and make GetBookChapterList return data for that page.  If you use entity framework, use the Skip and Take methods on IQueryable to implement the paging.

In the browser, render next/previous page links at the bottom of the table that gets and re-renders the data for the next/previous page.